# pine script line 23: Cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the security function

Tags: pine-script

Below code gives error. PinescriptVersion4

```
TrendUp     :=close[1]>TrendUp[1]? max(Up,TrendUp[1]) : Up 
TrendDown   :=close[1] 
Trend       := close > TrendDown[1] ? 1: close< TrendUp[1]? -1: nz(Trend[1],1) 
Tsl         := Trend==1? TrendUp: TrendDown 

Trend1 = security(syminfo.tickerid,"1",Trend)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your code in a function and pass that to the security call instead. https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/appendix/Pine_version_3_migration_guide.html#resolving-a-problem-with-a-mutable-variable-in-a-security-expression